# How to: Joomla Component on sub-domain

Tags: joomla, components, subdomain

Is it possible to have a Joomla component map to a subdomain? Such as forum or blog. If yes how?

blog.joomlasite.com ---> map to component page

Is there a plugin for it or is it possible via .htaccess tricks? Anyone done this before? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `RewriteRule blog.joomlasite.com joomlasite.com/componentmenuitem [R]` *SEF should be on*

Comment: @piotr_cz you should write your comment as an answer. Then HelloWorld can accept it as correct, and I can upvote it.

Comment: Jim > I wasn't sure if this is what HelloWorld was going for

Comment: Sorry guys. Yes that was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteRule blog.joomlasite.com joomlasite.com/componentmenuitem [R]`

*SEF should be switched to ON*